# How to understand the below macros in the code

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to understand the code base of an application but having issue in interpreting the below macros. Would any one please help me in understanding the code below.

```
#define LIST_OF_AP_COMMANDS(ENTRY) \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_SET_IP,         2, (WEP_MODE | WPA_MODE | NONE_MODE), "ifconfig wlan1 %s > /dev/null",                                         abAPIpAddress) \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_REMOVE_NETWORK, 2, (WEP_MODE | WPA_MODE | NONE_MODE), "wpa_cli -iwlan1 remove_network 0 > /dev/null") \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_ADD_NETWORK,    2, (WEP_MODE | WPA_MODE | NONE_MODE), "wpa_cli -iwlan1 add_network > /dev/null") \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_SET_SSID,       2, (WEP_MODE | WPA_MODE | NONE_MODE), "wpa_cli -iwlan1 set_network 0 ssid '\"%s\"' > /dev/null",               CON_acbSSID) \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_SET_PASS,       2, (WPA_MODE), "wpa_cli -iwlan1 set_network 0 psk '\"%s\"' > /dev/null",                CON_acPassword) \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_SET_PASSWORD,   2, (WEP_MODE | WPA_MODE | NONE_MODE), "wpa_cli -iwlan1 set_network 0 key_mgmt %s > /dev/null",           pcSecurityTypes[CON_bSecurityType] ) \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_SET_FREQUENCY,  2, (WEP_MODE | WPA_MODE | NONE_MODE), "wpa_cli -iwlan1 set_network 0 frequency %d > /dev/null",                CON_awWifiFreqs[ CON_bChannel ]) \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_SET_MODE,       2, (WEP_MODE | WPA_MODE | NONE_MODE), "wpa_cli -iwlan1 set_network 0 mode 2 > /dev/null") \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_SET_MODE,       2, WEP_MODE , "wpa_cli -iwlan1 set_network 0 wep_key0 %s > /dev/null", CON_acPassword) \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_SET_MODE,       2, WEP_MODE , "wpa_cli -iwlan1 set_network 0 wep_tx_keyidx 0 > /dev/null") \
  ENTRY(WLAN_AP_ENABLE_NETWORK, 10, (WEP_MODE | WPA_MODE | NONE_MODE), "wpa_cli -iwlan1 enable_network 0 > /dev/null" )

//! Expander with the execution of each command
#define EXECUTE_WLAN_COMMANDS(index, delay, mode, command, ...) \
    if( ( abSecurityModes[CON_bSecurityType] & mode ) ) { CON_cExecuteWlanCommand(command, ##__VA_ARGS__); } else { printf("wpa_cli %d %d\r\n", abSecurityModes[CON_bSecurityType], mode); } \
    sleep( delay );
```

Comment: gcc -E is not useful ?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: My guess is that the `LIST_OF_AP_COMMANDS` macro is expanded in more than one place with different text for the `ENTRY` parameter. But you have not shown any example where the `LIST_OF_AP_COMMANDS` macro is used.

Comment: Macro `LIST_OF_AP_COMMANDS` can be used with a macro name as its argument. In the example you can call `LIST_OF_AP_COMMANDS(EXECUTE_WLAN_COMMANDS)` which will call macro `EXECUTE_WLAN_COMMANDS` with every line in `LIST_OF_AP_COMMANDS(ENTRY)`, i.e. `EXECUTE_WLAN_COMMANDS(WLAN_AP_SET_IP, 2, (WEP_MODE | WPA_MODE | NONE_MODE), "ifconfig wlan1 %s > /dev/null", abAPIpAddress)` etc. The first argument `index` is not used here, so there are probably other invocations as @IanAbbott already wrote.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bodo, your comment helped me the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[X-macros](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) are a traditional technique for handling code generation in languages which use macro preprocessors like the C/C++ preprocessor. The idea is that you have a list of elements -- types, enumeration constants, message strings, etc. -- and you need to use that list more than once in order to generate your code.fir example, you might want to make both a list of error messages and an `enum` which defines symbolic names for each error. Or perhaps you have several different structures and you need to make two or more specific functions for each structure. (In C++, you would probably use templates for this particular case.)

The name "X-macro" comes from the original pattern in which the list macro invoked a macro with a given name -- by convention `X` -- on each element of the list, leading to a pattern like:

```
#define X(name, value) … // some use of name and value
HANDLE_LIST
#undef X

#define X(name, value) … // sone other use
HANDLE_LIST
#undef X

// etc.
```

But at some point, it became much more common to use a list-handler which takes the name of the macro to call as an argument (a so-called "higher order macro"). This allows for more meaningful names and avoids to need to repeatedly undefine `X`. (Particularly useful if you have miore than one list.)

And that's what you are seeing here.